# Java XOR decryption

Tags: java

I was given a custom Xor encryption function for a class project. The goal is to take this function and make a decryption function. It has been driving me nuts for a couple of days. Could anyone please help me?

If I input hello and use key password my output is: 35266a676e6e6d

Looking to reverse this.

```
class StringUtils {
    private static final char[] hexArray = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();

    StringUtils() {
    }

    private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        char[] hexChars = new char[(bytes.length * 2)];
        for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
            int v = bytes[j] & 255;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[(j * 2) + 1] = hexArray[v & 15];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }

    static String xor(String input, String key) throws InterruptedException {
        int index;
        String lengthString = input.length() + "&";
        byte[] buffer = new byte[(input.length() + lengthString.length())];
        int k_len = key.length();
        int index2 = 0;
        int c = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < lengthString.length()) {
            int c2 = c + 1;
            int index3 = index2 + 1;
            buffer[c] = (byte) (((byte) lengthString.charAt(i)) ^ (((byte) key.charAt(index2)) & 10));
            if (index3 >= k_len) {
                index2 = 0;
            } else {
                index2 = index3;
            }
            i++;
            c = c2;
        }
        int i2 = 0;
        while (i2 < input.length()) {
            int c3 = c + 1;
            int index4 = index2 + 1;
            buffer[c] = (byte) (((byte) input.charAt(i2)) ^ (((byte) key.charAt(index2)) & 10));
            if (index4 >= k_len) {
                index = 0;
            } else {
                index = index4;
            }
            i2++;
            c = c3;
        }
        return bytesToHex(buffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: XOR can be decrypted by using the encryption function again.

Comment: It looks like your assignment wants you to clean up this code first. Some stuff never gets used (like the variable `index`) and they wrote simple operations in weird ways (`c2` and `c3` only exist to make it harder to read).

Comment: @Robert This function makes use of XOR, but the function was badly named since it does not just XOR the Strings.

Comment: I don’t think the goal of homework is for someone else to do it for you. What have you tried for yourself?

Comment: In your second while loop where you have `if (index4 > => klen) { index = 0; } else { index = index4; }`  -- I suspect that should set `index2` instead of `index`.

Comment: Without that change, when you encrypt `hello` and decrypt again, you get `heldo`

Comment: @Erik I don't think he is allowed to modify that. I think that is just there to confuse people and make the problem harder.

Answer (score 1):

Without giving away the solution to your homework, here is a hint to help you get started.

### Hint 1:

After a little bit of refactoring, this is what the `xor` function looks like.

```java
static String xor(String input, String key) {
    String lengthString = input.length() + "&";
    byte[] buffer = new byte[(input.length() + lengthString.length())];

    int keyIndex = 0;
    int bufferIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < lengthString.length(); i++) {
        buffer[bufferIndex] = (byte) (((byte) lengthString.charAt(i)) ^ (((byte) key.charAt(keyIndex)) & 10));
        keyIndex = (keyIndex + 1) % key.length();
        bufferIndex++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        buffer[bufferIndex] = (byte) (((byte) input.charAt(i)) ^ (((byte) key.charAt(keyIndex)) & 10));
        bufferIndex++;
    }

    return bytesToHex(buffer);
}
```

### Hint 2:

You can determine the length of the input string by first taking a high estimate and reduce it by trial and error until you find the correct value.

```java
// Move input length down until it matches the calculation for buffer length
int inputLength = buffer.length - 1;
while (inputLength + (inputLength + "&").length() > buffer.length) {
    inputLength--;
}

// So now we know the length string
String lengthString = inputLength + "&";
```

### Hint 3:

There are three cases you need to account for from.

- `lengthString.length() > key.length()`: This case requires we find where the key repeats and grab the next character. This is doable, but may require additional work.
- `lengthString.length() == key.length()`: This is the easiest case to solve since it means the charater xored with the input is the first character in the key.
- `lengthString.length() < key.length()`: If this is the case, you won't be able to solve the problem as the byte used to xor the input is not in the length portion of the buffer. So for argument's sake just ignore this case entirely.

### Solution

I was bored so I decided to solve the problem. It just comes down to figuring out how long the `lengthString` portion of the buffer is. After that you can try doing it the smart way by checking for patterns or just list all of the 4 possible solutions since we know the input can only be XORed with 0, 2, 8, or 10 (because of the `& 10` earlier).

```java
static String extractSolution(byte[] buffer, int start, byte xor) {
    char[] solution = new char[buffer.length - start];

    for (int i = start; i < buffer.length; i++) {
        solution[i - start] = (char)(buffer[i] ^ xor);
    }

    return new String(solution);
}

static void decode(byte[] buffer) {
    // Move input length down until it matches the calculation for buffer length
    int inputLength = buffer.length - 1;
    while (inputLength + (inputLength + "&").length() > buffer.length) {
        inputLength--;
    }

    String lengthString = inputLength + "&";

    // Extract part of the key used in the first section
    byte[] keyFragment = new byte[lengthString.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < keyFragment.length; i++) {
        keyFragment[i] = (byte) (buffer[i] ^ (byte) lengthString.charAt(i));
    }

    System.out.println("Most likely solutions:");

    // Look for repeating patterns to find solution
    periodCheck:
    for (int i = 1; i < keyFragment.length + 1; i++) {

        for (int j = i; j < keyFragment.length; j++) {
            if (keyFragment[j] != keyFragment[j % i])
                continue periodCheck;
        }

        // A possible period has been found
        byte specialByte = keyFragment[keyFragment.length % i];
        String possibleSolution = extractSolution(buffer, keyFragment.length, specialByte);
        System.out.println("\"" + possibleSolution + "\"");
    }
    
    System.out.println("All Possible Solutions:");
    
    // List out all possible inputs that could have given this buffer
    // In reality key can only be one of [0, 2, 8, 10], but go through all bytes for verbosity
    for (int key = Byte.MIN_VALUE; key <= Byte.MAX_VALUE; key ++) {
        if ((key & 10) != key)
            continue;
        
        String possibleSolution = extractSolution(buffer, keyFragment.length, (byte) key);
        System.out.println("\"" + possibleSolution + "\"");
    }
}
```

[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Thank you so much for your input! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

A refactored version of your logic:

```
    static String encrypt(String input, String key) {
        String plain = (input.length() + "&" + input); // add length
        return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(xor2(plain.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), key.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
    }

    static String decrypt(String encrypted, String key) {
        String plain = new String(xor2(DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(encrypted), key.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        return plain.substring(plain.indexOf('&') + 1);  // remove length
    }

    static byte[] xor2(byte[] in, byte[] key) {
        byte[] out = new byte[in.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {
            out[i] = (byte)(in[i] ^ (key[i % key.length] & 10));
        }
        return out;
    }
```

... and a test case:

```
@Test
public void xorTest() {
    String message = "hello";
    String key = "password";

    String encrypted = StringUtils.encrypt(message, key);
    System.out.println("encrypted:  " + encrypted);
    String plain = StringUtils.decrypt(encrypted, key);
    System.out.println("plain:  " + plain);
}
```

This produces:

```
encrypted:  35266A676E666D
plain:  hello
```

Comment: I am not sure if they are given the key when solving since it seems to be more of a reverse engineering challenge. I'm guessing that the length was added so they could attempt to find the key in there. However my assumption is mostly based on the roundabout and semi-obfuscated way the `xor` function was written.